# Issue in dynamically added select list

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

in my project,(Edit page) i have an input box that contain the value from db. and place a div over that input box(when page loading that div is not shown). my need is when i am clicking on that input box i want to enable the div and show as a drop down select list. i am using following code,

http://jsfiddle.net/wzPYf/1/

```
 <div class="role">
       <div style="float:left;">In Rotary Club of Puthencruz : &nbsp;</div>
       <div class="currentrole"><input type="text" value="@Model.Mem_Role" name="Mem_Role" id="memrole"/></div>
     <div class="allrole"></div>
   </div>
```

//jquery

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('#memrole').click(function () {
    $('.allrole').attr('disabled', false);
    var arr = [
        { val: 'member', text: 'Member' },
        { val: 'president', text: 'President' }
    ];
    var sel = $('<select>').appendTo('body');
    $(arr).each(function () {
        sel.append($("<option>").attr('value', this.val).text(this.text));
    });
    $('.allrole').html(sel);
});
```

});

//css

```
.role {
position:relative;
display:inline-block;
}

.currentrole {
position: absolute;
margin-left:100%;
width:200%;
}

.allrole {
position:absolute;
width:150px;
height:20px;
margin-left:100%;
display:none;
}
```

But my jquery part is not working, the dropdown select list is not displayed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your code to this -

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#memrole').click(function () {        
        var arr = [
            { val: 'member', text: 'Member' },
            { val: 'president', text: 'President' }
        ];
        var sel = $('<select>');

        $(arr).each(function () {
            sel.append($("<option>").attr('value', this.val)
                .text(this.text));
        });

        $('.allrole').html(sel);
        $('.allrole').show();
});
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wzPYf/6/).

The mistake that you were making was - to show a hidden div, you need to call jQuery's **[show](http://api.jquery.com/show/)** method on it. Setting disabled attribute to `false` doesn't work here.

Also you can simply create a `select` element by calling $(''), no need to append it to a body, since you are already attaching it to the `.allrole` div later. Next, rather than assigning the the select element with options as a text, I simply appended it to the `.allrole` div.

Comment: :actually allrole div is not displayed

Answer (score 1):

If you want to show the div which is `display:none` or `visibility:hidden` just use `$(yourselector).show();` So your code would be

```
$('.allrole').show(); instead of 
$('.allrole').attr('disabled', false);
```

The working demo is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/wzPYf/4/) Refer [show()](http://api.jquery.com/show/)